# I can't access Object proprieties

Tags: reactjs

I have an  which value is a custom object ({"value": "a","path":"b"}).
When I try to access object.value I get that is undefined, I tried to console log the object and I get [object Object], if I try to console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject)) I get in the console "[object Object]" with the "". When I set the input value I print the object and it works, but when I try to access the value from the onChange I get that

Here is the code:

```
{listaElementi.map((elemento, index) => {
                    return (<li key={index}>{elemento.value}<input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => elementoSelezionato(e)} value={elemento} /></li>);
            })}
```

Where I fill the listaElementi

```
querySnapshot.forEach((el) => {
                        setListaElementi((prev) => {
                            return [...prev, {
                                value: el.id,
                                path: el.ref.path}]})
                    })
                })
```

This is the function that runs on onChange:

```
function elementoSelezionato(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            elementiSelezionati.push(e.target.value);
            var myobj = e.target.value;
            console.log(myobj);
        } else {
            var index = elementiSelezionati.indexOf(e.target.value);
            console.log(index);
            elementiSelezionati.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(elementiSelezionati);
        }
        
    }
```

The part where I fill the array works and I can see all of my elements in the list

Comment: @MWO it doesen't change anything I get the same error